# How would I make an indented swirl around this sphere

Tags: modeling

How would I go about making an even swirl from the bottom to the top that is indented?
I figure you would just insert it, but I don't know how to cut the swirl shape into the object.

I tried to use the knife tool but it doesn't make a uniform curve around the object.
[image: Object]

Comment: unclear what you want , please elaborate

Comment: You could use a knife tool to cut a "swirl path", then select the whole path, bevel it slightly so it becomes a "channel", and then extrude the channel inwards (extrude faces along normals).

Comment: What do you mean by swirl? Could you add some drawing?

Answer (score 21):

A way to do it is to start with a UV sphere which has a lot of rings. For instance, 360 rings or 720 depending on the amount of turns you want to give to the swirl. Keep segments as default (32 or so).

[image]

Having these many rings allows to proportionally rotate around Z the summit of the egg for n times 360 degrees.

Here set proportional editing on, set the fallog to linear, and use <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>360</kbd>. Make sure the proportional editing sphere reaches the bottom of the egg. Repeat it for each turn you want to give.

[image]

Now select an edge loop joining the top and the bottom. Set proportional editing to smooth, and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale only on X Y and lower the proportional editing sphere so that it influences few vertices around the selected edge loop.

[image]

Can also animate the twist... using a simple deform modifier:

[image]

In that case, same principle but rotate nothing first just make the indent.
Then add the simple deform modifier and animate the angle:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You could do it this way:

- Create a plane, rotate it 90° on the X axis, apply the rotation, subdivide it 20, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* (*Iterations* > 1 in the *Operator* box):

[image]

- Bevel and extrude the oblique edge:

[image]

- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier /*Bend* mode, with a *Deform Angle* of 360°:

[image]

- Create a cube that contains the plane, display it as wireframe, scale it, subdivide it:

[image]

- Give your plane a *Mesh Deform* modifier with the cube as *Object*, click on *Bind*. Select your cube, give it a basis shapekey then a second one, go in *Edit* mode and scale it so that it deforms the plane until it looks like an egg:

[image]

- Give your plane a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add some bevel to sharp the edges, apply the modifiers, fill the holes, etc...

[image]