# How Can I Make A Spiral Around A Cone

Tags: modeling

I came across this render by someone and in order to improve my skills, I decided to try it hands on but I am currently stuck on how to create that spiral mesh around the cone like object in the front. I have tried a number of stuff including using the bezier curve and simple deform modifier but I am not getting it right. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: That also seems to do the trick. I'll try it and see

Comment: @Emir This question is different from the one you cited, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, please. It is not a duplicate

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193249/how-would-i-make-an-indented-swirl-around-this-sphere/193266#193266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the curve: extra objects add-on:

then do this:

[image: Add Object menu showing Archemedian Spiral selected]

increase height, decrease radius growth, increase turns

[image: Resulting spiral and last operator panel]